Why can't CLion correctly read Chinese strings from a TXT file?
As a Chinese university student studying computer-related majors, I am working on a major assignment assigned by my teacher to create a restaurant management system. However, when I finished my code, I found that CLion cannot correctly read the dish names stored in the TXT file.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried using '%s' to input the string and '%49[^,]' to make it understand the content before the ',' but neither worked. Additionally, I also tried changing the input method by using '\n' to make it read the content before the newline character, but it still couldn't effectively write the dish names.
void loadMenuFromFile(const char *filename) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.GBK");
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");



    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("无法打开文件");
        return;
    }

    // 初始化 itemCount 为 0

    char line[100]; // 用于存储读取的整行数据

    // 读取文件，直到文件末尾
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("读取行: %s\n", line);  // 打印读取的行

        int result = sscanf(line, "菜品ID: %d\n 名称: %49[^\n]\n 价格: %f\n 成本: %f\n",
                             &menu.items[count].id,
                             menu.items[count].name,
                             &menu.items[count].price,
                             &menu.items[count].cost);

        if (result == 4) {
            printf("成功解析: ID=%d, 名称=%s, 价格=%.2f, 成本=%.2f",
                   menu.items[count].id,
                   menu.items[count].name,
                   menu.items[count].price,
                   menu.items[count].cost);
            count++;  // 成功解析后增加 itemCount
        } else {
            printf("解析失败，读取行内容: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("菜单数据已从文件 %s 加载，读取了 %d 个菜品\n", filename, count);
}

void loadMenuFromFile(const char *filename) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.GBK");
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");



    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("无法打开文件");
        return;
    }

    // 初始化 itemCount 为 0

    char line[100]; // 用于存储读取的整行数据

    // 读取文件，直到文件末尾
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("读取行: %s\n", line);  // 打印读取的行

        int result = sscanf(line, "菜品ID: %d, 名称: %49[^,], 价格: %f ,成本: %f",
                             &menu.items[count].id,
                             menu.items[count].name,
                             &menu.items[count].price,
                             &menu.items[count].cost);

        if (result == 4) {
            printf("成功解析: ID=%d, 名称=%s, 价格=%.2f, 成本=%.2f",
                   menu.items[count].id,
                   menu.items[count].name,
                   menu.items[count].price,
                   menu.items[count].cost);
            count++;  // 成功解析后增加 itemCount
        } else {
            printf("解析失败，读取行内容: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("菜单数据已从文件 %s 加载，读取了 %d 个菜品\n", filename, count);
}



void saveMenuToFile(const char *filename){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("无法打开文件");
        return;
    }

    // 将菜单项写入文件
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "菜品ID: %d 名称: %s 价格: %.2f 成本: %.2f",
                menu.items[i].id, menu.items[i].name, menu.items[i].price, menu.items[i].cost);
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("菜单数据已保存到文件 %s\n", filename);
}


I tried everything except Json part.......I don't know why it can't scanf words from txt to menu correctly.
the txt words coding is GBK and clion's product is GBK too.

fgets by definition reads a single line, i.e. up to and including the newline character '\n'. So trying to look for it with sscanf will not work. And besides, it doesn't work as you expect in any scanf function, where all white-space characters (including newline, tab, space and a couple more) are all treated the same.

sorry,so how can I find the Chinese characters correctly?I fprintf them in a line,I can't use fgets or gets to get them,I don;t know how to get them except sscanf

The string values in the code are probably encoded with UTF-8 by default. Do you know what character encoding was used in the TXT file? You may need to use iconv() to convert the text, or compile the code to use the same character encoding as the TXT file.

the coding type about them are at the end of the question,I change the txt characteristic code and the product,they are all GBK

well,but what's pity was that in VScode(gcc or mgw)they can run and get correctly with the same code product,but in clion,they can't.

You may need to set the GCC compiler options -fexec-charset=GBK (or whatever) to set the executable character set to GBK and -finput-charset=UTF-8 (or whatever) to set the character set the C source code uses.

the Cmakelist's set is C standerd 11 and all project settings are GBK,it can run correctly in VScode which was totally using GCC and MGW.While it's can't get correctly in Clion.Other codes has no problem and it can read and write Chinese in other coding context but it can't read Chinese characters correctly from txt that they don't know where they ends I guess .I think it's the Clion own problem but I couldn't solve it.
